# Blazor OIDC after login user can click back and go to /signin-oidc

Tags: .net, blazor, .net-6.0, openid-connect, blazor-server-side

I am experiencing an issue with OIDC routing and users actions after login on Blazor - .Net6.

After a successful login the user is redirected to "/". But he can click the back button in the browser which will redirect him to the **/signin-oidc** route where he will get an UnhandledException: Correlation Failed.
Same behavior if the user tried to manually access that route.

How can I prevent user from manually accessing that route? It seems that all the events/triggers I have in place don't detect the navigation to that path.

I have tried subscribing to the NavigationManager.LocationChanged event in the mainlayout but it doesn't detect uri changes that go outside the domain/body known routes.

***Edit 1***

I have found a way to manipulate the call to this route. If a user manually navigates to that route or he clicks the back button and gets there, the route logic will think a remote login already took place and it will treat it as a Remote Login Failure.

We can then use the oidc event OnRemoteFailure. In here we redirect the user to a page where we have access to the authentication state. If the users appears as not authenticated then there was indeed an error in the login process and we can show how him a message indicating that.

But if the user is authenticated, it means he either hit the back  button or he manually tried to navigate to that route after he was already authenticated and we can safely redirect him to **"/"**.